# Ruby on Rails: Iterate model values from another model before_create / before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a RoR app which lets people post anonymously, given that they would put their email address in a field.

The model goes like this.

Post model.

```
post.rb
  belongs_to :user # optional: true --> this is for rails 5
```

user model

```
user.rb
  has_many :posts
```

My post model has these columns: title, body, user_email:string, user_id:integer

My user model came from devise gem.

In my app, I am letting user post without logging in or without signing up. These means that they can create post, and the user_id column will be blank (because they need to input their email).

However, what I want to achieve is if they signed up to my app, all the post associated with the user they registered should change the user_id column to its corresponding user.id. So in my user.rb model, I added this code.

```
# user.rb
before_save :associate_post_to_user

def associate_post_to_user
  Post.all.each do |post|
    if post.user_email == self.email
      post.user_id = self.id
    end
  end
end
```

However, whenever they create an account, the value of user_id in post do not change. How do I achieve this? I am using devise gem btw. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues in your codes:

1. There is no **post.save** after **post.user_id = self.id**
2. Use **Post.all**, The SQL will query all Post records，There will be performance problems.

May be you can change it like this:

```
    def associate_post_to_user
       Post.where(user_email: self.email).update_all(user_id: self.id)
    end
```

Comment: thanks for this! This is really helpful. I didn't know there is a helper called update_all. BTW, how do you know these helpers? Is there a specific book that teaches all of these?

Comment: Read the rails api frequently, it will help you more.The reference is https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Answer (score 1):

Since `before_save` hook is defined for your `User` model, you need to `save` your `Post` instance explicitly.

```
# user.rb
before_save :associate_post_to_user

def associate_post_to_user
  Post.all.each do |post|
    if post.user_email == self.email
      post.user_id = self.id
      post.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I though that doing post.save would be redundant as the model is currently not saved yet (that's why before_save). Now I know it isn't Thanks!